# Trouble storing the size of each array I have in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble storing the size of each array the user inputs. I need to do this so that I can run different calculations on each set. This is what I'm trying to do now, but it keeps throwing a segmentation fault, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The other thing I thought of doing was essentially make one more memory spot with malloc and just store the sizes in another array at the end of the data set arrays. Anyway, here's the code that is giving me a segmentation fault.

```
int construct_data_sets(int *sets[], int count) {
    int set_size;
    int j;
    j = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements in data set %d: ", count+1);
    scanf(" %d", &set_size);
    sets[count] = (int*)malloc((sizeof(int) * set_size));
    if (sets[count] == NULL){
        printf("Malloc failed!\n");
    }
    printf("Enter the data for set %d: ", count+1);
    while ((j + 1) <= set_size)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &sets[count][j]);
        j++;
    }
    return set_size;
}
```

And here's the main, I think the segmentation fault gets thrown when I call construct_data_sets().

```
int main() {
    int command = 0, data_set, set_desired, array_size;
    int number = prompt_num_sets();
    int *sets[number], i = 0, *sizes[number];
    while (i < number)
    {
        array_size = construct_data_sets(sets, i);
        *sizes[i] = array_size;
        i++;
    }
    //printf("The size of the 3rd data set is %d", *sizes[3]);
    printf("Data at [data_set][1] = %d\n", sets[data_set-1][1]);
    set_desired = select_data_set(number);
    while (command != 7) {
        printf("Choose what you would like to do:\n");
        printf("1. Find the minimum value.\n");
        printf("2. Find the maximum value.\n");
        printf("3. Calculate the sum of all the values.\n");
        printf("4. Calculate the average of all the values.\n");
        printf("5. Sort the values in ascending order.\n");
        printf("6. Select a different data set.\n");
        printf("7. Exit the program.\n");
        scanf(" %d", &command);

        if (command == 7) {
            exit_program();
        } else if (command == 6) {
            change_term(number, sets);
        }
        printf("====================================\n");
    }
}
```

Any weird printf statements you may see are just me trying to make sure things are doing what they're supposed to. Let me know if you need more information from me. Thanks.

Comment: If you tell us where the segmentation fault occurs (ideally giving us the specific line), it will make it much easier for us to help you with your problem.

Comment: Where do you allocate the memory for sets?

Comment: `while((j + 1) <= set_size){ scanf(" %d", &sets[count][j]);` : if `type array[N]` then use range of index is 0..(N-1).

Comment: the code is not compilable by itself, so I cannot run it and confirm :(

Comment: `int *sizes[number];*sizes[i] = array_size;` --> `int sizes[number];sizes[i] = array_size;`

Comment: This code is *begging* for a `struct set { int *data; size_t len;}`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple bugs in your code and several stylistic issues. Have you tried running the code in the debugger to see exactly where things are crashing? Have you tried narrowing the code down to a smaller problem?

Your `sizes` array should have an element type of `int` instead of `int *`. You are dereferencing uninitialized memory since you have not allocated anything for the pointers. Your `data_set` variable is also uninitialized so the array access into `sets` is also undefined.

You should initialize all of your variables immediately upon definition. Also I would change your code to declare only one variable per statement. The current code is quite difficult to read.

I would also change your initial `while` loop into a `for` loop.

Here's a working version that doesn't crash; although, since you haven't included all of the code, I don't know if there are other parts that are broken. I've also had to remove the references to the undefined functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int construct_data_sets(int *sets[], int count) {
    int set_size;
    int j;
    printf("Enter the number of elements in data set %d: ", count+1);
    scanf(" %d", &set_size);
    sets[count] = (int *) malloc((sizeof(int) * set_size));
    if (sets[count] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Enter the data for set %d: ", count+1);
    for (j = 0; j < set_size; ++j) {
        scanf(" %d", &sets[count][j]);
    }
    return set_size;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int command = 0;
    int number = 1;
    int *sets[number], i, sizes[number];
    for (i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        sizes[i] = construct_data_sets(sets, i);
    }
    printf("Data at [0][1] = %d\n", sets[0][1]);
    while (command != 7) {
        printf("Choose what you would like to do:\n");
        printf("1. Find the minimum value.\n");
        printf("2. Find the maximum value.\n");
        printf("3. Calculate the sum of all the values.\n");
        printf("4. Calculate the average of all the values.\n");
        printf("5. Sort the values in ascending order.\n");
        printf("6. Select a different data set.\n");
        printf("7. Exit the program.\n");
        scanf(" %d", &command);

        if (command == 7) {
            return 0;
        } else if (command == 6) {
            return 0;
        }
        printf("====================================\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```